# Пытаюсь создать калькулятор на питоне. Помогите исправить ошибки

Tags: python, калькулятор

```
# калькулятор
wtf = input( "что делаем?  ")

a = float(input("введи первое число"))
b = float(input("Введи второе число"))

 if wtf == "+":
    c = a + b
    print(c)
    elif wtf == "-"
     c = a - b
     print(c)
else
print("ошибка")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
wtf = input( "что делаем?\t")

a = float(input("введи первое число:\t"))
b = float(input("Введи второе число:\t"))

if wtf == "+":
    c = a + b
    print(c)
elif wtf == "-":
    c = a - b
    print(c)
else:
    print("ошибка")
    
input('Завершено') #задержать просмотр результата в консоли
```

В языке Python нужно сохранить правильное форматирование и придерживаться синтаксиса. После условий нужно двоеточие.

Answer (score 1):

Я когда только начинал учить python, писал основных действия(сложение, умножениее, вычитание, деление)

```
a = input('Что делаем?(+, -, *, /):')

if a == '+':
    b = float(input('Первое слагаемое:'))
    c = float(input('Второе слагаемое:'))

    result = b + c
elif a == '-':
    b = float(input('Уменьшаемое:'))
    c = float(input('Вычитаемое:'))

    result = b - c
elif a == '*':
    b = float(input('Первый множитель'))
    c = float(input('Второй множитель'))

    result = b * c
elif a == '/':
    b = float(input('Делимое:'))
    c = float(input('Делитель'))

    result = b / c

print('Результат:' + str(result))
```

Comment: Чтобы не приводить типы для конкатенации, можно легче использовать интерполяции, так называемые f-строки. `print(f'Результат: {result}')`

Comment: Конечно. Просто, опять же, когда я учился по гайдам на ютубе, в первых конечно же рассказывалось в первую очередь про конкатенацию, я с тех времён привык к ней.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать прикольный однострочный калькулятор так:

```
while True: print(eval(input()))
```

Comment: Причём со всей Python-мощью :D

Answer (score -1):

```
a = input('a    ')
b = input('b    ')
c = input("знак:+,-,*,/   ")
if c =='+':
    print(float(a) + float(b))
elif c=="-":
    print(float(a) - float(b))
elif c == "*":
    print(float(a)*float(b))
elif c == "/":
    print(float(a)/float(b))
else:
    print('error: print valid function')
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]